# Giza++ installation, FORTRAN problems

Tags: makefile, fortran, fpic, giza++

I am trying to install Giza++ and Moses on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit. While make I keep on getting the same problem:

```
Finished building giza

cp ../lib/libgiza.a /usr/local/lib/
```

................................

```
giza-pgplot.o -L/usr/X11R6//lib -lX11 -L/usr/X11R6//lib -lcairo -lm  -L/usr/local /lib/x86_64/ -lgfortran

/usr/bin/ld: giza-fortran.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

giza-fortran.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[1]: *** [../lib/libpgplot.so] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/maria/moses/giza/build'

make: *** [install] Error 2 "
```

Googling did not help much. I would be very grateful for any tip of how to solve this problem. What should I do to recompile it with -fPIC?

Comment: What compile command is actually being used?

Answer (score 1):

This problem existed only with the giza check out from the svn. This one from tar.gz http://code.google.com/p/giza-pp/downloads/list installed without any problems. Whatever it was...